# Get path in dynamic route in Next JS when Server Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I need to get the path in a dynamic route in Next JS. This is easy to do in a client component.

In src/app/[id]/page.tsx

```
"use client";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function Page() {
    const pathname = usePathname();
```

However you can't use `usePathname` in a Server Component. How do you get the url in a React Server Component in Next JS 13?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server [`page.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page) component gets passed a `params` object when it's in a dynamic segment. And this `params` would contain your dynamic route id, like so:

```
// app/[id]/page.tsx

export default function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const { id } = params;

  return <div>{id}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above makes you to do a ton of propdrilling...

Better use this approach which eliminates prop drilling.

```
// your-server-component.tsx

'use server'

import { headers } from 'next/headers'

const YourServerComponent = async () => {
    const pathname = headers().get('next-url') || ''

    // I assume you know how your path will look like so make some 
    // logic to extract the dynamic part from the pathname and use 
    // it however you want in this server component. For example 
    // fetch specific Post from you backend

    const postId = pathname.split('/').pop() || ''

    const postResult = await fetch(`www.your-domain.com/api/posts/${postId}`)
    
    const post = result.json()

    return <p>{post.title}<p/>
}
```

Comment: There is no prop drilling in the answer above, as the prop is passed by Next.js. That's what the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) recommends. [Prop drilling is when you, the developer, have to pass a prop down in a very nested hierarchy](https://dev.to/codeofrelevancy/what-is-prop-drilling-in-react-3kol). What you are doing is a hack not granted.

Comment: The above answer is including a lot of prop drilling. Imagine if the RSC is deeply nested into the page. It means you need to pass that props throught all the components till you reach the one that is going to use the data. Would be perfect if Nextjs introduced same props as for Layouts and Pages for RSC aswell. Would be OP. 

Howerver my answer is not perfect aswell due to i got some inconsistency with getting the dynamic part from URL. Somehow the dynamic part is not added to the URL on initial page load.... It works only on Soft navigations using <Link/>.

Comment: So i ended up with prop drilling instead and then it worked perfectly.