How to get dynamic route parameters in a server action?
I'm using NextJS 14.2 and try to access a dynamic route parameter on a server action of my PageComponent. There route is app/events/[eventId]/register/page.tsx. In a register server action I want to access [eventId] now. In the server component is it possible via the params function parameter, but on the server action?

have you tried pass the [eventId] as an argument for server action?

I don't think that's possible since params are only for page routes.

yes but aren't you using them in some page or components?
if not, can you please add you code structure to question?

It is already answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173839/get-path-in-dynamic-route-in-next-js-when-server-component?rq=2
